# Kubernetes DemonSet With Cluster Role

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I've created a python script that load the node resource.
by running the following script. the error is forbidden.
Before the script call , the `config.load_incluster_config()`
has been called.

### Script:

```py
  def fetch_node_resource(cls, node_name: str) -> Resources:
        # config.load_kube_config()
        api_client = client.CoreV1Api()
        node = api_client.read_node(node_name)

        # Fetch all node resources
        capacity: dict = node.status.capacity

        cpu_capacity = Maybe.from_optional(capacity.get("cpu", Nothing))

        memory_capacity = Maybe.from_optional(capacity.get("memory", Nothing))

        network_bandwidth_capacity = Maybe.from_optional(
            capacity.get("network_bandwidth", Nothing)
        )

        gpu_capacity = Maybe.from_optional(capacity.get("nvidia.com/gpu", Nothing))

        return Resources(
            cpu=cpu_capacity,
            gpu=gpu_capacity,
            memory=memory_capacity,
            net_bandwidth=network_bandwidth_capacity,
        )
```

#### Error:

```
"node-exporter-simulator-sbcqr\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:monitoring:node-exporter-simulator-account\" cannot get resource \"nodes\" in API group
```

A service account was given CLusterRole & binded.
The Script itself runs as a DaemonSet.

#### Demonset:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.nodeExporterSimulator.enabled }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: node-exporter-simulator
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: node-exporter-simulator
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-exporter-simulator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-exporter-simulator
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: node-exporter-simulator-account
      containers:
        - name: metrics-generator
          image: dev0guy/node-exporter-simulator:v0.0.5
          env:
            - name: PROMETHEUS_GATEWAY_URL
              value: "pushgateway:9091"
            - name: PUSH_INTERVAL
              value:  {{ .Values.nodeExporterSimulator.interval }}
{{- end }}
```

#### Roles:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: node-exporter-simulator-account
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: node-exporter-simulator-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: node-exporter-simulator-binding
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: node-exporter-simulator-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: node-exporter-simulator-account
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
```

I've runned `helm install` command How ever I'm always getting 403 Forbidden error.
I've kubectl describe for all of the resources, however all of them seems correct.

As any one solved this problem before, or there is any advice ?

### Edit:

The problem has been fixed, there was a name error. (didn't gave the same name of the account service).
How ever the problem I've no its that I need to get the node name but instead I'm getting the pod name

Comment: How is your Python code authenticating to Kubernetes? Please include code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the script function (of getting node) was added. 
You can see the all repo in  https://github.com/dev0Guy/NodeExporter

Answer (score 0):

First I searched by the node name , but instead it was the pod hostname. After fixing that I've passed a pod name and its name space inside the daemonset. However I didn't added a a pods to the cluster roles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).